# Php mail form successfull message on same page

Tags: php, forms, email, format

I am using php mail form on my page. It work good but when email is sent the message about successful post is opened in new blank page. What I want to do is show message directly under send button with some formating. My code looks like this.

```
<form action="contact.php" method="POST" id="contactform_main2" style="font-size:14px">
                    <ol>                    
                      <li>
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="text" required />
                      </li>             
                    ....etc
                      <li class="buttons">
                        <input type="submit" name="imageField" value="Odoslať" class="send" style="cursor:pointer" />                     
                      </li>
                    </ol>
                  </form>
```

and this is the php

```
<?php
...geting data
if(
  mail("dominik0109@gmail.com", $subject,
  $sprava, "From:" . $email)){
  echo "<strong>Sucessfully sent</strong>";}
  else {
  echo "Error";}
?>
```

You can see it live on [my page](http://mmiuris.sk/kontakt), fill any content to post form.
How to fix this please?
Thnaks

Comment: This means contact.php isn't the page you are on now. You should change it to your current page

Comment: You are submitting form to the page `contact.php` which is different than your current page. Leave the action empty or just put "?" and it will submit to the current page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to send the form to the same page and check if POST variables are passed.

## mypage.php

```
<form action="#message" method="POST" id="contactform_main2" style="font-size:14px">
                    <ol>                    
                      <li>
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="text" required />
                      </li>             
                    <!-- ....etc -->
                      <li class="buttons">
                        <input type="submit" name="imageField" value="Odoslať" class="send" style="cursor:pointer" />                     
                      </li>
                    </ol>
                  </form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
// ...geting data
  echo "<a name='message'></a>";
  if(mail("dominik0109@gmail.com", $subject, $sprava, "From:" . $email)){
    echo "<strong>Sucessfully sent</strong>";
  }
  else {
    echo "Error";
  }
}
?>
```

If you are looking not to refresh the page at all you'll need javascript and ajax.

Comment: thanks now its woking, hoverever the succesful message is down and you need to scroll. I wouldnt mind refreshing if it would be possible to open page on some anchor on refreshing. Wolud it ?

Comment: add a <a name='message'></a> just above your messages and replace <form ... action='mypage.php' .. /> by <form ... action="#message" .. />

Comment: without the / of /> sorry ^^' I'll edit my post to include the tag anchor